# UrlConnection not opening HttpsUrlConnection

Tags: java, ssl, https, java-me

I'm trying to connect to secure http via Java Embedded Machine.

i have running self signed apache server on port 8090. When i use web browser to navigate to `https://myserver:8090` it shows self signed certificate warning and loads ok.

I have this code

```
        URL dstUrl = new URL("https://myserver:8090")
        URLConnection result = dstUrl.openConnection();


        System.out.println("Protocol: "+dstUrl.getProtocol()+", is HTTPS:"+(result instanceof HttpsURLConnection)); 
// Echo: Protocol HTTPS is HTTPS:false

        if (result instanceof HttpsURLConnection) {//will not reach
            try {
                HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) result;
                conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
                conn.setHostnameVerifier(defaultHostVerifier);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //sout will not ignate
            }
        }
        return (HttpURLConnection) result;
```

This code should function fine but the openConecction() will allways return HttpUrlConnection and not HttpsUrlConnection. Is there any chance i can force opening HttpsUrlConnection if i know that protocol is https?

EDIT:

My Imports:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
```

EDIT 2:

I've found out on the issuers site that there should be a `URLStreamHandlerFactory` applied at start of machine so https protocol is returned by deprecated `com.sun.net.ssl.internal.www.protocol.https.Handler`

now i know that HttpsUrlConnection by javax is not returned but a `com.sun.net.ssl.HttpsUrlConnection`

Thanks anyway

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this isn't an issue with your server? Trying your code with `https://www.google.com` returns an HttpsURLConnection for me, as does testing with a local server using a self signed certificate.

Comment: I've tried. The same it's always HttpUrlException. I Think it is because of deprecated Java on the machine.

Comment: Are you using the right imports?

Comment: I've added list of my imports to question